# list all files matching a given pattern

Tags: bash, unix, find

I have a directory /folder1/folder2 containing two type of files:

- file.txt
- file.txt0* (* means any number)

I wrote a script to list all files matching pattern "file.txt0*" occurrencies in folder "/folder1/folder2":

```
find -wholename /folder1/folder2/file.txt0*
```

But it always returns nothing.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Be sure to quote the argument so that the shell doesn't expand the pattern before it is passed to `find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you are in proper relative directory. below should work, if you in root folder and `folder1/folder2` are present in `/` (root)

```
find /folder1/folder2 -iname file.txt0*
```

`-i` does a case-insensitive search.

Answer (score 4):

`-name` searches for the filename and not for the path. You would need to write the search like this:

```
find /folder1/folder2/ -name file.txt0*
```

Comment: You should quote `file.txt0*` or it might be expanded by the shell before `find` gets to see it.